# How to make markets for highly liquid assets?

Tags: market-making

I'm looking at the level-2 data of some ETFs and trying to figure out whether it's possbile to design a market making strategy. When looking at the data, I find these ETFs to be highly liquid: at the top of the book, all price levels are next to each other by just one price tick and with very large volume, leaving me no space to insert my orders and the only choice seems to be waiting in the queue.

I have no experience in market making and the situation seems to indicate that there's no liquidity premimum any more to capture in these assets. I'm guessing there are already many designated market makers working on these assets and competiting with each other, thus leaving no room for later players.

My question is, what should a market maker do if he/she tries to enter this market, or how do existing market makers gain advantage over competitors?

Comment: As you say, you have to wait in queue. With a high volume you will get to the front of the queue soon enuf

Comment: For background on order book dynamics, you may want to read: Smith, E., Farmer, J. D., Gillemot, L., & Krishnamurthy, S. (2003). Statistical theory of the continuous double auction. Quantitative Finance, 3(6), 481.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't.

You get paid to provide liquidity. Sounds like none is required.

For you to make money, you need to transact with a bid-ask spread in your favor.  To get to the head of the queue, you could purchase order flow or otherwise find a place where you have priority interacting with flow (perhaps "internalized" flow).

There is a balance between *the book turning over* (enter at the end of the queue, proceed to the front with volume, and have size remaining behind you when filled, aka price unchanged); and,  *the book being run over* (you are filled, but the market traded through you).